# Error : Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, ecmascript-6, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add a listener to my Database using Firebase.

```
const dbRef=firebase.database().ref().child('messages');
dbRef.on('child_added', MS.bringData);
```

When something is added, I execute `bringData` which creates a new object called `message` from the `snap` object.

```
export const bringData = (snap) => {
  const message1=new Message(snap.val().objet, snap.val().message, snap.val().etat, snap.val().key);
  message1.creerLigne();
}
```

Then I call `creerLigne()` from the class `Message`, to create the new line and add it to `tbody`

```
creerLigne() {
     const arg=[this._objet, this._message, this._etat, this._id];
     const row=document.createElement("tr");
     row.setAttribute('id', this._id);
     const data=document.createElement("td");
     var checkB=document.createElement("input").setAttribute('type', 'checkbox', 'name', 'delete');

     var i=0;
     while(i<arg.length-1) {
         let data1=data.cloneNode();
         let text=document.createTextNode(arg[i]);
         data1.appendChild(text);
         row.appendChild(data1);
         i++;
     }

     data1.appendChild(text);
     row.appendChild(data1);
     row.appendChild(checkB.cloneNode());
     document.body.appendChild('row');
}
```

but unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of undefined
    at Message.creerLigne
```

Comment: You use `cloneNode` twice. Even if the error message doesn't say the line, it should not be difficult to figure out which one.

Comment: Basic debugging is all you need here. What have you done so far to solve this on your own? If you're not aware, you can use `console.log()` as a quick, simple way to check values. The more powerful debugging tools are very important to learn how to use too. This may be a good time to start.

Comment: ...and learning to consult API documentation is important as well. There's actually another issue on the line that is the source of this problem.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, it's the second cloneNode because the line `var checkB=document.createElement("input").setAttribute('type', 'checkbox', 'name', 'delete');` doesn't return an element, THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: @squint THANK YOU FOR YOUR ADVICES, it's all about debugging and using API documentation, I used the `console.log()` many times to resolve the problem, it was very helpful

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you got things working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkB=document.createElement("input").setAttribute('type', 'checkbox', 'name', 'delete');
```

should be

```
var checkB=document.createElement("input");
checkB.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
checkB.setAttribute('name', 'delete');
```

`.setAttribute` does not return the element, and it only takes two arguments.

Comment: No problem, it happens :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 creerLigne(){
                 const arg=[this._objet,this._message,this._etat,this._id];
                 const row=document.createElement("tr");
                 row.setAttribute('id',this._id);
                 const  data=document.createElement("td");
                 const checkB = document.createElement("input");
                 checkB.setAttribute('type','checkBox');
                 checkB.setAttribute('name','delete');
                 let i=0;
                    while(i<arg.length-1)
                    {
                     const data1=data.cloneNode();
                     var text=document.createTextNode(arg[i]);
                     data1.appendChild(text);
                     row.appendChild(data1);
                   i++;
                 }
               row.appendChild(checkB.cloneNode());
               const table= document.querySelector('table');
               table.appendChild(row);
             }
```